# Copy os-release content from inside docker container

Tags: linux, docker, shell, symlink, cp

I need to capture host's `os-release` from inside the alpine docker container. If I directly run `cp /etc/os-release /path/file` command inside the container, it copies the details of alpine linux. I also tried binding /etc to one of the container paths, but as /etc/os-release is a symlink, it could not fetch the actual OS details when I tried capturing it.

Is there any other ways that I can achieve this. Assume that the content of os-release may change due to an OS upgrade.

Comment: Use [build args](https://docs.docker.com/build/guide/build-args/)

Comment: As in the host where the image was built, or where the container is running?  Since you can't access any of the host's filesystem, why does its distribution (if any) matter?

Comment: @Max Build args configure how you create the image, not a container based on the image.

Comment: Can you run `docker cp /etc/os-release container:/path/file` from the host ?

Comment: @Philippe That manual change will get lost as soon as the container is deleted, and deleting and recreating containers is pretty routine.  I wouldn't recommend `docker cp` for normal use.

Comment: Use a ENV variable? `docker run -e OS=<the value> myimage`, inside container you can read the value `printenv OS`

Comment: @DavidMaze I just gave the alternative to OP's command `cp /etc/os-release /path/file`